# Permission Based instead of Role Based

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my application, a User is assigned multiple Roles, and a Role is assigned(granted) multiple Permissions.
So in my code, I never check against a Role, but always against a fine grained Permission.

Here is described why I think Permissions based access is better than Role based:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/299732

Within Azure AD, I can assign roles to a user.
But I see no way of creating Permissions and associate them to Roles, so I guess this part must stay in my app ?

Then how should I link the Azure Application Roles to my app's Permissions ?

My assumption is I need to build an UI for doing this, using the Graph API to retrieve the list of roles defined in Azure for the application.
If that is the case, then I don't see much benefits using the built-in roles function in Azure vs keeping the role definition in my app...

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point of using Azure AD claims is to keep users information in the Active Directory rather than in the application.

In you case, you need to create permissions mapped to roles in your application.
Then theses roles can be mapped to Azure AD AppRoles or Groups.

I suggest you not to map directly users to roles.
If you deals with Group, you don't need to add/remove users to/from applications: Roles and permissions are inherited from groups users belong to.

1. Mapping directly to Groups

   For the moment, it would be my preferred scenario. Users are assigned to groups and your customs roles are mapped to these groups.
   When you create a new user, you just need to add it in some groups and there is no action required in your application (same things when you delete the user).
   If you are not afraid of preview (and have an Azure AD Premium license), Azure Ad provides a way to [dynamically assign users to group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-accessmanagement-groups-with-advanced-rules/).

Just keep in mind that for the moment [nested group memberships aren't currently supported](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-accessmanagement-manage-groups/).
So if a Group A is in Group B and Group B has some permissions in your application, Users from Group A will not have permission inherited from Group B.

2. Mapping Groups to application roles

   This option seems to be an overkill because it requires one more step: Map Azure Ad Group to Azure Application Roles and Map theses roles to your custom roles.
   You need to implement all this logic using the AAD Graph API and your UI will be more complex.

Only reason to use this option in your scenario is if you have a large directory with lots of groups and applications : If a user is in more than 200 groups so the Jwt token returned by the Azure AD will not contain the groups and you will have to query one more time the Azure AD to get the user groups ([see](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/)).
In this scenario, it could make sense to map groups to application roles because when a user authenticates to an application, Azure Ad will always provides you the roles of the users (or the roles of the group that the user belong to)

you can find interesting code sample here:

- [active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console).

Comment: Awesome Thomas, great food for thought ! And yes, if you can share some bits, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin, sorry very busy for the moment. I've edited my post. There is a link with Azure Ad code sample. I'll try to post my own later.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, Azure Active Directory application roles are meant primarily for the scenario where each user can only have one role and thise roles are mapped to a simple authorization model.

While it is technically possible to support multiple roles per user, that can only be managed via the Graph API and would require you to build a UI for your user admin / users to manage.

As you've noted, your scenario is more complex than this with multiple roles per user and multiple (potentially customizeable and overlapping) set of permissions.

Given these two points, your approach of implementing all of the authorization yourself is a sound one.

Check out this article which outlines in more details the authorization scenarios Azure AD is best suited for:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-multitenant-identity-app-roles/

Comment: this is not true. You can map multiple app roles to a user and even map group to app roles but this is not available via the azure portal. you need to use the Azure Ad graph API to do it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be clearer about the fact that it is possible to have multiple roles assigned via Graph, but that you'd then need to build your own UI. That fact paired with the other requirement of configurable permissions per role makes the value of app roles limited for this scenario and thus makes the in-app implementation of authorization a better fit.